# Which Raptor survived?

Tags: jurassic-world

In Jurassic World, Owen names his 4 raptors. Pretty sure they were named Blue, Charlie, Delta and Echo. Blue was the Beta, with Owen as the Alpha. Is there any way to know which of these Raptors survived in the end?

Comment: In addition to it visibly being Blue in the movie (the stripes are visible), I'm pretty certain Starlord actually refers to her by name.

Comment: Starlord?  [Who?](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/906/648/aa4.jpg)

Comment: @phantom42 Are you planning a Jurassic World/Guardians of the Galaxy crossover fan fic? (Because I would totally be on board with that concept)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think we all would.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### The raptor named Blue survived. She was the last to arrive to the fight and her challenge to Owen (Pratt) at the end was foreshadowed earlier in the movie.

- After T-Rex and Blue defeat Indominus Rex: Blue turns back to Owen and the others in fuller view, there is a moment when Owen purposefully shakes his head ‘No’. The battle being over, Blues instincts could return to normal, but with her parental figure Owen saying no she realizes they are all family – not food – and runs off as well.
- It is implied in many of the articles written about the movie that it is Blue who is the most successful protagonist of Jurassic World.

  > So while Claire makes googly eyes at Owen and flees from pterodactyls, Blue’s journey through Jurassic World is a lot more interesting, and has an actual arc. In two hours, she leaves the only home she’s known, must make quick decisions about who to trust, and ultimately puts her life on the line for the side of her choosing. And—unlike Claire—she’s practical enough not to wear heels.
  >
  > **REF: [Slate: The Best Female Character In Jurassic World Is a Velociraptor](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2015/06/12/the_best_female_character_in_jurassic_world_is_a_velociraptor.html)**

Comment: I know you didn't write that, but it seems unfair to imply Claire didn't put her life on the line considering she released a T-Rex and had it chase her

Comment: @childcat15  Agreed.  And, as one article pointed out, Claire's heels never become an obstacle or a hindrance to her during the story (i.e. she never falls down or breaks a heel and has to be rescued), so the "sexist" or "impractical" argument kind of breaks down.

Comment: She may have put her life on the line but it was unnecessary in the way she did it. I could count a dozen scenarios where she should have died but didnt, just solely because the writers thought she would play to the audience better alive. The last part with the rex where shes in heels? Ever seen Deep Blue Sea? Remember at the end where she wanted to attract the shark but jumped in the water without any escape plan? or really without the need to even jump in at all? that scene with the rex immediately reminded me of Deep Blue Sea. The fact that she didnt die doesn't make her any less worthless.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it was blue. Also, I think the last communication was her asking if the Alpha (Pratt), to whom she had just proven her allegiance, was ready to leave. He shook his no he wasn't coming. Which makes blues sacrifice and final exit alone pretty tragic.(for a raptor)

Answer (score 4):

The film's [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553536907) (based on the screenplay) makes it clear that it was Blue that survived:

> The T. rex snarled. It was weakened by injuries, but victorious. **The
>   T. rex and Blue looked at each other, unsure whether to fight. The T.
>   rex turned away, choosing not to. Blue gave Owen a farewell glance,
>   then disappeared into the shadows.**
>
> The T. rex looked up at the moon and lumbered off into the night, free
>   to roam the island.

You can (in the film) also see her distinctive "blue" stripe.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It was Blue who was the last surviving raptor. You could see the blue stripes on her body when she walked into the plaza during the fight, and after when she was saying goodbye to Owen

This site has the final fight: http://www.fatmovieguy.com/spoiler-alert-watch-jurassic-worlds-epic-final-battle/

Answer (score 0):

It was Blue - the first Raptor to die was blown up, and we don't know which one it was, but it wasn't Blue because Blue is the one Owen interacts with when they're surrounded and the Indominus (I-Rex) is on the other side of the Raptor. Blue then screams at I-Rex and they all attack, but Blue is the first to get flung at a wall, and while it looks painful, it's clearly non-lethal because we know the bond Blue and Owen share, if Blue was going to die, it would be emotional and Owen would be holding her head. The next Raptor to die is the one that gets flung on the grill and goes up in flames - clearly dead, then, just before Claire goes and gets Rexy, you can see I-Rex flinging the other Raptor around in its mouth like a rag doll, and it can be safely assumed, considering the bite force of this animal is supposedly the same as the T-Rex, that any animal the size of a Raptor that gets between those jaws is going to be dead. Then, the final obvious clue to it being Blue is the fact that when she comes running out all dramatic like and distracts I-Rex, so Rexy can knock her over, the Blue streaks, unique to Blue and assumedly the inspiration behind her name (instead of Bravo, which would follow the trend, as the phonetic alphabet goes Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo etc). We also know they're unique because we see all the raptors and none of the others have it. It was Blue.

Comment: "it's clearly non-lethal because we know the bond Blue and Owen share, if Blue was going to die, it would be emotional and Owen would be holding her head" - actually, I was convinced she was dead while watching that scene. Especially the way the camera remained on her for what felt like an extended moment, and the subsequent charging of the other two raptors had me 100% certain that she had sacrificed her life to cause the remaining two raptors to fight on Owen's side in order to revenge her death. (Nonetheless I agree it *was* Blue who survived, "brought back from the dead" by the script.)

Answer (score 0):

Blue was the last stand.... blue was the one that was talking to i-rex and Owen while they was all together. Blue was the first one to be attack the i-rex grab the one talking and throw her. The other two went to attack i-rex after blue was through in the wall (not dead) who was  Charlie (with the green like stripes) and delta (was the one with the circle kinda a greenish pattern) fighting i-rex. Echo was blow up way before has a brownish color to her. Echo was thrown into the build and burned. Delta was through off the scene not sure if they wanted us to think she was dead or not but hurt nonetheless. When the t-rex came you will see blue came running from the direction she was through and came to fight against the i-rex. The others was thrown in the other direction look at the scene. Blue was the one who survived you can also tell by the color. 
You can see the pattern more when he talks calls them earlier in the movie at the point he feeds them.

Answer (score -2):

No that is incorrect. Check the wikis before posting. Blue clearly survived. Charlie blew up. Echo was barbecued. There is some speculation about whether or not Delta survived being tossed by the I. Rex.

Comment: Can you add some proof of what you're claiming? As a first time poster this was flagged for length and content. Generally you want to make a point, use a quote and/or link, make a point, quote/link, etc. So in this case you should axe the first two sentences. Put something like, "I have a different take." Then write "Blue survived, and here's how we know that _____" quote/link, and continue. Please edit your post to make it more meaningful. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: “Check the wikis before posting.” There is no such obligation here!

Comment: Also, when leaving an answer, try not to refer to other answers for yours to make sense; this is not a conversation thread, and your answer may bubble to the top, or the other answer may get edited/deleted, and then your first line won't make sense :)

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to commend on an earlier answer